# Which is the best tool Generate Hibernate map from MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, servlets, orm

I am using hibernate in my servlet to access the database.DB contains lot of foreign keys, composite keys and backward references..

Can you suggest me some tools to do reverse engineer the MySQL DB to Object oriented file in java so that I can use it with hibernate.

Comment: Please mark an answer, ..

Answer (score 2):

IDEs usually provide such generating of entities.
For example, if you use Netbeans, just go File/New/Persistence/Entity Classes from Database within a Java SE/Java EE-Project to generate JPA entities.
By the way, it's a good idea to use standard JPA(2) mechanisms where possible, in order to not being dependant on a specific O/R-Mapper (such as Hibernate) or database.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Cris,

The version 0.5.5 of [Minuteproject 4 JPA2](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/JPA2) generates also for composite key a class annotated with @Embeddable. The entity class has the @EmbeddedId as entity with the reference to the Embeddable class. For the foreign keys part of the composite key, it generates the associated @MapsId.

Meanwhile the JPA2 templates do not cover yet the composite foreign key pattern.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [JBoss Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) which allows you to reverse engineer existing databases.

Comment: I have tried using it.. But it gave me wrong mapping when it comes in the case of composite keys.

Comment: Hibernate Tools gives you the option to implement your own reverse engineering strategies (See chapter 6.3. Custom strategy). Given enough complexity in your database layout almost every generic reverse engineering solution will come to its limitations. Maybe you are expecting to much here out of the box.

Comment: Yes.. If the tools are not gonna work I'm gonna write it manually.. Learning cure is little bit high on this framework.

Answer (score 1):

The best one is MinuteProject in my opinion !

Check it on :

http://javacodesamples.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/jpa2-reverse-engineering-tool/

http://www.dzone.com/links/jpa2_reverseengineering_with_minuteproject_pragma.html

http://javacodesamples.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/minute-project-episode-1-the-productivity-provider/

It has also a Spring + Hibernate track beside the JPA so you can used that for you hibernate needs.

Answer (score 1):

We use **Hibernate Tools** to generate `*.hbm.xml` files with the help of a `hibernate.reveng.xml` file. And then, we apply **Hibernate Synchronizer** plugin of Eclipse to generate Entities and DAOs using `*.hbm.xml` files.

`hibernate.reveng.xml` fill the parts where auto generation cannot guess what you have in your mind.

Hibernate Synchronizer has the main advantage of creating **base classes** for your generated entities/daos. You add your custom properties/methods to **subclasses** (again automatically generated) of the base classes. The advantage here, is if you make changes to your database and regenerate, the changes you make (to subclasses) rest untouched.

Whatever tool you choose pay attention to build a system where code generation is easy and painless, not only for the first time but also during advanced phases of the project. If not you'll lose all the advantages.